# handling embedded videos width height for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website page. I used bootstrap to create it. It is responsive and works great on most elements.

Except the one embedded vimeo video. I configure it as follows:

```
 <div class="col-md-7">
        <iframe src=$VIDEO_URL controls=false
           width="640"
           height="400"
           frameborder="0"
           webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
        </iframe> 
 </div>
```

As you see I have fixed width and height. This creates issue on mobile device and it does not fit the width of device.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok..I solved it by using media queries

```
@media(max-width:639px) {
        iframe {
                width: 480px;
                height: 300px;
        }
}

@media(max-width:320px) {
        iframe {
                width: 320px;
                height: 180px;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using min-width/max-width or min-height and max-height for the embebded video OR you could set width/height to the container div instead of the video itself ( and set the video width/height in auto/percentage).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which browsers officially support this, but you can use "100%" instead of a number of pixels in the width and height of an iframe to scale your video without getting into the CSS.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pjpwea/pw8btzky/